# Scrolling a tr/element inside a popup table

Tags: css, html-table, overflow, responsive

I am updating the style of a very old website and I can't change the server code (only the style).

My problem here is that I have a div popup containing a table that overflow (in y) outside the div because of one tr which is very long.

I can't set an overflow on the div container because I need to see the top and the bottom (really old html design, with the first tr is the top bar, and the last tr the bottom  bar). It's the second (middle) tr which need to be scrolled (or the inside content).

I didn't found an answer that fit my problem.

I tried to use different type of display, such as `block`, but I can't really get a nice thing. For example, it seems fine, but the bottom tr is completly at the bottom of the page while the middle tr is cut and scrollable.

I'm not really experienced with css different type of display so I tried to read about it on w3schools and use some, but it didn't went well.

Here is a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ex8h2Lgm/

```html
<div id="popup">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>

      <tr class="border" id="top">
        <td colspan="5">popup</td> <!-- normally 5 td, but not relevant-->
</tr><tr id="middle">
        <td class="border" id="left"></td>
        <td id="center" colspan="3">
          <div>
            <div id="1" class="content">Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 1 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2</div>
            <div class="content" id="2">Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br> Content 2</div>
            <div id="3" class="content">Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3 <br> Content 3</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="border" id="right"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border" id="bottom">
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#\31  {
  background-color: blue;
}

#\32  {
  background-color: red;
}

#\33  {
  background-color: green;
}

/* #right { */
.border {
  background-color: grey;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#top, #bottom{
  height: 20px;
}
#left, #right{

}
#center{
  width: 100%;
}
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#\31  {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

As I described above, I want the table to be same size as the div, with only the middle tr scrollable, so the top/bottom tr aren't scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is restricted to change HTML structure. It is quite challenging here.

I chose the approach to override HTML tag's default style from browser even some native tag that shouldn't be overridden (you have to test this very carefully in every supporting browser because each browser has different default style)

Here's the style that I added. I'm not sure if it's going to work with your popup but I hope you get the idea

```css
table {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
#middle {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#center {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krugtep/ufydepro/3/

Answer (score 1):

Write less code for better performance this will work in all browser.

```
table, tbody, #center {
     display: grid;
}
#middle {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

Comment: Your solution and the above one are both nice, thanks for your help.
However, I had to chose one, and while yours is good, forcing the height with a fixed size bother me a bit (using a percentage size need a bit more style to move the bottom tr)
So I chosed the other one. 
Thanks again